# How to add mesh collider into trees in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I added palm trees on my terrain. But I didnt add a mesh collider into the trees.

My car is able to pass through them.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you give the code where you added the palm trees?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved problem with box collider. Box colliders are covering all of the trees and no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both the car and the trees have a mesh collider. Some more explanation of your problem would be nice.

Comment: The car have a mesh collider. The trees is not game object. So I didnt add it. The trees were added from here : terrain->inspector-> terrain(script)->place trees. Is there a way for add mesh collider into such the trees?

Comment: You can use GameObject.addComponent<meshCollider>(); to add a meer collier to the trees

Answer (score 0):

Prefabs include a Capsule collider,Sphere collider or any simple collider is working but mesh collider when plant trees or any prefabs by Terrain Place Trees method.

A tree use Capsule collider is fine but a stone maybe use a simple mesh collider better than a Sphere collider. and unity don't let we do.